# C# xsd xmlreader, how to count attribute names

Tags: c#, xsd, xmlreader

This is probably very simple for you guys, but I need to be able to count the attribute names within an xml document when validating xml against a schema using c#. Specifically duplicate attribute names (not valid).

### If my xsd has these in it:

```
<xsd:schema>    
<xsd:complexType name="scheduleEvent">     
    <xsd:all>     
        <xsd:element name="Basic" type="MyBasic"/>
    </xsd:all>
 </xsd:complexType> 
   <xsd:complexType name="MyBasic">    
    <xsd:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">    
        <xsd:element name="Descriptor" type="Descriptor" maxOccurs="1"/>     
        <xsd:element name="Descriptor1" type="Descriptor1" maxOccurs="1"/>    
   </xsd:choice>    
   </xsd:complexType>    
   <xsd:complexType name="Descriptor">    
    <xsd:attribute name="Test" type="typ:Test"/>    
   </xsd:complexType>    
   <xsd:complexType name="Descriptor1">    
      <xsd:attribute name="Test1" type="typ:Test1"/>    
  </xsd:complexType>
```

And my xml to validate against looks like (not valid, I know just a quick mock up example for reference:

Declarations etc...

```
<ScheduleEvent>
 <MyBasic>
  <Descriptor Test="02"/>
  <Descriptor1 Test1="02" Test1="02"/> 
</MyBasic>
</ScheduleEvent>
```

How can I count the number of "Test1" attributes? C# xmlreader  (without using exceptions, long story).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, that isn't a valid xml. An attribute is unique per element.

If what you ment is that you can have multiple "Test1" attributes throughout the different elements, then you can do the following using [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx):

```
var xml = XDocument.Load(@"PathToXml");
var testCount = xml.Descendants().Attributes("Test1").Count();
```

Comment: Thanks to both Yuval and Thirisangu for the answers here. I ended up bypassing the xsd exception that was providing the schema exception messages, to exclude certain duplicate errors. But thanks for the suggestions, noted for future usage!

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
XDocument doc=XDocument.Load(XMLFile or XMLFilePath);
var Sample=doc.Descendants("Test1").Count();
```